# Redirect whole page from imported JSP

Tags: java, jsp, redirect, jstl, response.redirect

I have two jsp, let's say `A.jsp` and `B.jsp`. `A.jsp` has the following code:

```
<c:import url="B.jsp" >    
    <c:param name = "page_title" value = "Title" />
</c:import>
```

In `B.jsp` i need to check some conditions and do a redirection to `Login.jsp`. I achieve this by doing `response.sendRedirect(Logn.jsp)`

The problem is that the redirection is made on `B.jsp` so the result is that the browser displays the content of `Login.jsp` and `A.jsp` but i need to redirect the whole page to `Login.jsp`. That is, the browser should only show `Login.jsp`.

Consider that the redirection must be made on `B.jsp` unless there is a way that `B.jsp` can tell `A.jsp` the url to redirect to.

**EDIT:** `A.jsp` and `B.jsp` belong to different projects

Answer (score 0):

In your `B.jsp`, instead of doing a *redirect*, set a flag on the *`request`* as

```
<c:set var="login" value="true" scope="request" />
```

Then in `A.jsp` check the flag and *redirect* if present.

```
<c:if test="${login == 'true'}">
    <c:redirect url="/login.jsp" />
</c:if>
```

---

Try doing a `jsp:include` instead.

```
<jsp:include page="B.jsp" >    
    <jsp:param name="page_title" value="Title" />
</jsp:include>
```

Comment: That does not work. login in null in A.jsp. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to solving this:

1)  Making sure that you are not sending any HTML to the client in A until you have performed the logic in B.  That means that you must call the B.jsp early (part of good MVC design).

2)  Use the var parameter in your c:import:

```
<c:import url="B.jsp" var="output">
```

Now the output of the call to B will be in a *buffer* called "output" instead of being sent directly to the client.   That allows you to make decisions in A (after the call to B).   If you decide you want to redirect, you can, because you have dumped nothing (except some white space probably) to the browser.   If you decide you want to send the output of B to the browser instead you can simply do this after the c:import:

```
${output}
```

There is even a trick to get rid of the white space being sent to the browser if that becomes necessary, but it rarely is (if you send too much white space the buffer will commit and then you cannot redirect, but that's rare and an entirely different question).

Make sense?